# C: how to fill a table with fgets() if we don't know the length?

Tags: c

I'm trying to fill a table word by word with the method fgets(). I need to fill  a table with words(max 25) that the user write step by step. The problem is that on my terminal if I do for exemple :

- ab    (then press Enter)
- ac    (then press Enter)
- ad    (then press Enter)
- tu    (then press Enter)
- (then press ctrl+d to stop)

The output is:

- tu
- tu
- tu
- tu

So basically it just copy the last word for each input I've entered

I've tried to replace "tab[length] = line;" with "strcpy(tab[length], line);"
but when I do this I've got a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

```
#define NBRE_CHAR 256

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   
    char* tab[25];
    int length =0;
    char line[NBRE_CHAR];
    while(fgets(line,NBRE_CHAR,stdin) != NULL){
        line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0'; // to delete \n
        tab[length] = line;
        length++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", tab[i] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong terminology. [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) is not a method. Compile with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Provide a [MCVE] in your question

Comment: Assigning a pointer does not copy the pointed-to object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char* tab[25];` is an array of 25 *pointers* to characters (strings).

With `tab[length] = line;` you asign the buffer `line` to the array. But that doesn't copy the string. As a result, all entries point to your single line buffer, which will have your last entered string.

What you may want is:

```
    char* tab[25];
    //...
        tab[length]= malloc(strlen(line)+1);
        strcpy(tab[length], line);
```

This allocates memory for each string and then copies the contents of your buffer to this memory.